# UIScrollView in UICollectionViewCell gestures handling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've seen people with similar problems here, but couldn't find any working solution. I have a UICollectionView, with fullscreen cells. I scroll the content horizontally (paging enabled). Each cell has a UIScrollView as a subview, which covers the entire cell. My problem is that when I use zoom-in functionality of a UIScrollView, I can't scroll from one cell to another unless I zoom-out to 1.0 scale or reach a border of a UIScrollView content. My idea was to use two-fingers pan gesture to scroll the collection view, so I could use one finger to scroll cell's internal UIScrollView. It doesn't work and I simply have no idea why. I can provide more details, but for now I don't know what might be important.